# why is my ArrayList empty even though firebase datasnapshot contains children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to pull user data from firebase realtime database, the datasnapshot does contain children and data but when I attempt to put this into an array, the array is empty. I created a user class which contains the properties to match the ones in firebase, overloaded constructors, and some methods. It does not extend any class though as I know this would not work with retrieving data from Firebase.

```
private List<user> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference ref = databaseReference.child("Users");

public List<user> getUsers(){
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.i("users", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));

                for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    user userRetrieved = child.getValue(user.class);
                    Log.d("USER before array", userRetrieved.getUserName());
                    usersList.add(userRetrieved);
                    for(int i = 0;i < usersList.size(); i++){
                        Log.d("USER", usersList.get(i).getUserName());
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("ERROR", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return usersList;
}
```

All feedback welcomed.

Comment: Where's the nullpointer exception located? or where's the failure happening in your code? please add more explanation to your code

Comment: Did you mean to say that your ArrayList is empty (instead of null)?

Comment: Correct it is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, had to make sure my class was conforming to the object being returned from the DB. First I had to make my user class implement serializable and add `@PropertyName()` and also make sure all the property names matched exactly what was in the Firebase.

```
 public List<User> getUsers(){
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try{
                for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User User = childSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    usersList.add(User);
                        User[] UserArray = new User[usersList.size()];
                        UserArray = usersList.toArray(UserArray);
                    for(int i = 0;i < usersList.size(); i++){
                        Log.d("NAME", UserArray[i].getUserName());
                    }


                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Error in the try", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("ERROR", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return usersList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase APIs are asynchronous.  `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` returns immediately, and the callback you pass to it is executed some time later, after query completes.  There is no guarantee how quickly that will happen.  Meanwile, your function is returning a list that's initially empty.  You probably have code that's to read it with the assumption that the query has already completed, when it actually hasn't.

Bottom line is that you should only deal with the results of the query after the callback has been invoked, not before.

Comment: The log statement for the username though works and logs the username if that were the case wouldn't that be null as well?

Comment: That log is **inside** the callback, which executed only after the data is available.  That's how the callback works.  The code is not executing top the bottom. The callback is invoked **later** when the query completes.  It might be worthwhile to learn about how asynchronous programming works in Java.